# Case statement not working

Tags: shell, case

Its part of my program,

```
output="$(./t1)"        // output=5

echo $output            // It displays 5

if test $output -eq 5
then
echo "five"             // this if statement works and displays 'five'
fi

case $output in          **// this case is not working and giving just default value**

1) echo "one" ;;

2) echo "two" ;;

3) echo "three" ;;

4) echo "four";;

5) echo "five";;

*) echo "wrong choice" ;;

esac                    // output is wrong choice though it works proper in if statement
```

Is there any mistake in my bash script?
Please help.

Comment: strange. In my bash your program works OK a prints 5, five, five. (Ofc, I removed all illegal // comments).

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
output=$(./t1)
echo $output
if test $output -eq 5; then echo "five"; fi
case $output in
  1) echo "one" ;;
  2) echo "two" ;;
  3) echo "three" ;;
  4) echo "four";;
  5) echo "five";;
  *) echo "wrong choice" ;;
esac
```

When you had the `"` around `$(./t1)` the result was a string, not a numeric value. This worked with `test`, but not `case`. Also you has a couple of missing `;` in the post and `//` is not valid for comments in bash.

Comment: try: `a="5"; case $a in 5)echo "five";; *) echo "other";; esac;` will print "five". And the ';' are needed only when the whole if statnement is in one line (as in your answer). The construction what used the user in his queston is fully legal. Using '//' is the problem.